# If an azure function is down, are the other functions in same app down too?

Tags: azure-functions

I have two Azure Functions. The first is a HTTP Trigger which receives a request to process data, the second is a Blob Trigger which makes the same processing with a file instead of web data. The second function is supposed to be a backup to the first function, does that make sense? I mean, is it possible for one azure function to be down and the other to be working even if they are in the same Function App Project?

Comment: How do you define the "down" state of an Azure function?

Comment: Not working for a network or Azure problem for instance

Comment: You say `I mean, is it possible for one azure function to be down and the other to be working even if they are in the same Function App Project?`, this  is possiable. The answer you mark is talking about another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Functions, Function App is the unit of scale. Per Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#how-the-consumption-and-premium-plans-work):

> An instance of the host is the entire function app, meaning all functions within a function app share resource within an instance and scale at the same time.

I take it as if (for whatever reason) the function app (instance host) goes down, all functions in that FA will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can.

You just need to disable one function. Then the function been disabled will not run. But this will not affect others.

For example, if you do something like this:

[image]

[image]

In above function app, I create two functions. One is HttpTrigger1 and another is HttpTrigger2. If I disable HttpTrigger2, then it will be shutdown and HttpTrigger1 will keep on running.

On local, you can check below document to disable function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function

(Please notice that when you don't use script language, function.json will not work.)

Answer (score -1):

If the host(function app) is unable to load, then none of the constituent functions get loaded and same goes for what happens when the function host goes down as well.